# MD5.Create() throws NullRefrence

Tags: c#, md5

The following line throws `NullRefrenceException`:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void newUser(string name, string password,string email)
    {
        var db = new ORMDataContext();
        var user = new User();
        Console.Write(password);
        user.email = email;
        user.password = MD5.Create(password).ToString();
        user.username = name;
        db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        this.Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.Id));


    }
```

I checked and *password* is not null, nut somehow md5-ing it returns *null*.

Comment: let me put the whole method

Comment: I think you can easily find out which one is null by debugging...

Comment: As a side matter from all of this, I'd urge you to consider using a more secure approach for storing the password. See https://adambard.com/blog/3-wrong-ways-to-store-a-password/ for example. This is *really, really* important if this is going to be a public service; if this is only for a hobby project then it's less important, but a good idea to get into good habits. (In fact, the best habit here would be to try to find a trustworthy user management module so you don't need to write this kind of code at all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the argument that[`MD5.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0412464z.aspx) expect is *algorithm* name.

Modify and use it this way.

```
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passowrd));// logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you use the `MD5` class. Try this:

```
using(MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
  user.password = 
         Convert.ToBase64String(md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)));
}
```